# scrollTop not working within sidebar nav / div

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, sidebar, scrolltop, scrollable

I have a web page with a bootstrap-styled fixed scrollable sidebar menu on the left side, and the main content on the right side.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul id="mainMenu">
         <li id="menuItem1">item 1</li>
         <li id="menuItem2">item 2</li>
         <li id="menuItem3">item 3</li>
         .
         .
         .
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <div id="content">
      Main contents goes here on the right side...
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css for the sidebar menu:

```
#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
#content {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here's some javascript codes I have tried to scroll the sidebar menu to a certain item so that item gets scroll up into view.  I test by using some fix scroll value

```
document.getElementById('sidebar').scrollTop = 400;
document.getElementById('menuItem20').scrollIntoView();
location.href = "#menuItem20";
```

None of the above codes are working.  I can scroll the main content part of the page with javascript, but I just can't get the left menu to work.  Note: the left menu scrolls fine by using mouse scroll wheel.  Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: can you make this more clear please, perhaps add a full example illustrating the problem

Comment: Can you set a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help.  I figured out the problem.  I'm using a template I found on the web for the sidebar menu, and the template uses a plugin called "mCustomScrollbar".  This is what is preventing the normal javascript scrolltop from working.  Fortunately the plugin does supply its own scroll function.  This is what works for me:

```
var yOffset = $("menuItem20").position().top;

$("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
   theme:"minimal"
});

$("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", yOffset);
```

The purpose of this piece of code for me is to always auto-scroll the active menu item into view when the web page reloads.  One can also use window.innerHeight to calculate the best yOffset to center the active menu item, but that is not within the scope of this question.